# Let $b_n = \sqrt{n ^ 3 + 6n-1} - \sqrt{n ^ 3-10n-11}$ then $\lim_{n → ∞}b_n =?$

Tags: limits

I have a problem with the following task:

Let $b_n = \sqrt{n ^ 3 + 6n-1} - \sqrt{n ^ 3-10n-11}$

Then $\lim_{n → ∞}b_n =?$

Attempt:

$(\sqrt{n ^ 3 + 6n-1} - \sqrt{n ^ 3-10n-11})\cdot\frac{\sqrt{n ^ 3 + 6n-1} + \sqrt{n ^ 3-10n-11}}{\sqrt{n ^ 3 + 6n-1} + \sqrt{n ^ 3-10n-11}}$
$= \frac {16n+10}{\sqrt{n ^ 3 + 6n-1} + \sqrt{n ^ 3-10n-11}}$
$= \frac {n(16+\frac{10}{n})}{\sqrt{n ^ 3 + 6n-1} + \sqrt{n ^ 3-10n-11}}$

How exactly do I proceed with the $n^3$ in the denominator, or which $n$ makes sense to exclude there and why ?

I am very happy about your help.^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

As $n>0,$

$$\sqrt{n^3+6n-1}+\sqrt{n^3-10n-11}=n^{3/2}\left(\sqrt{1+\dfrac6{n^2}-\dfrac1{n^3}}+\sqrt{1-\dfrac{10}{n^2}-\dfrac{11}{n^3}}\right)$$

Comment: So i can say, i take out $n^\frac{3}{2}$ on counter and denominator and we get $\frac{0}{2}$ and $lim b_n =0$?

Comment: @Vek, You are right